# window.setInterval to start only when I click the start game button and need to get that without using functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, setinterval

I want the `window.setInterval` to start only when I click the start game button and need to get that without calling a function for SetInterval.Right now the `setInterval` works as soon as the page is loaded and generates random letters.

I have tried the following code:

(The start game button)

```
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3"><button id="rndletter">Start game</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("rndletter").addEventListener("click", window.setInterval(function() {

                var result0 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
                

                var result1 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
                

                var result2 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
                

                document.getElementById("result0").innerText = result0;
                document.getElementById("result1").innerText = result1;
                document.getElementById("result2").innerText = result2;
            },2000));
</script>
```

Comment: `...addEventListener("click", function() {setInterval(function() { ... }, 2000);});`

Comment: That would be the correct answer except the OP doesn't want to use functions for some reason.